# which process was running on a particular time in linux

Tags: linux, process, logs

Is there any way to find which process was running on a particular time in linux?

I found the disk utilization was 99% and CPU utilization was 100% on two different times yesterday. The issue was resolved automatically, but I need to find which process or user causes the issue.

I used `sar -d -f /var/log/sa/sa11` to find disk utilization. Util was 98% from 11:10:01 to 11:40:03.
and `sar -P ALL -f sa11` to find cpu utilization. user was 99.36% from 8:40 to 9:50.

After that everything was normal without any restart.

I need to know which process(es) causes the utilization so high.

Answer (score 0):

By default, and depending of your distro, there is not much recording of what is running. 
Your only chance is that may be the application leaves a message in some log located in `/var/log/` which you can spot using time slot analysis.

A more accurate way is to explicitly monitor each exec syscall which you can achieve using `auditd` daemon. But this mean installing, configuring and running this daemon.

Comment: auditd is running on my vm. How can I get the information of that particular time?

Comment: first you can see what is logged in `/var/log/auditd/`, depending of the rules applied you can have some luck (or not)

Comment: There is no file or dir named /var/log/auditd. I checked auditctl -l. It returns "No Rules".